# FindControl() returning copy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to use FindControl() to SET the values of some DropDownLists on a page.

for some reason,  it appears that FindControl() is returning a copy of the control object as opposed to a reference, I was under the impression that this would not be the case due to the lack of a copy constructor for Controls?

<EDIT>

Ok, it apparears that it is not in fact returning a copy, it's simply not letting me set the visibilty of a control, the other properties I'm setting work fine.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this might be the case?
I've tried setting it in quick-watch mode then looking at the value straight away, and that isn't actually changing the value either!

</EDIT>

<EDIT> (two)

Ok, I'm doing this in Page_Load, and it's not in a gridview (I like how you guys assumed that one cus I was using FindControl()).

I'm doing this as there is a set of operations I have to perform on a dynamic number of similarly named lists, and it's MUCH better to do it in a loop than to hard code it.

</EDIT>

Can anyone help?

Cheers, Ed

Comment: It doesn't copy controls. There has to be something else wrong about.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought -> did some more testing -> updating question.

Comment: PS: if you're hiding the panels, there's no need to set the controls inside them to invisible.

Comment: I'm not, I was just doing the visible operation on the wrong control =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
Whoa, wait... are you setting the Visible property to `true` rather than false?
In your comment, you mention it changes back instantly. The `Visible` property will evaluate to `false` if it's parent is set to be invisible, no matter how often you tell it the value should be `true`.

Comment: Sorry, the actual number of dropdowns is not dynamic, it's the number that are visible/editable that is, and this changes based on a large number of criteria. And the control is getting set to visible=false immediately after I call the visible=true, as if it was only a copy.

Comment: Shit, totally forgot that they were all in invisible panels with their titles. . . .duh.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Where are you calling `FindControl()` and setting the `Visible` property?

For info, `FindControl()` gets a reference to a control in the current naming container, based on a string `id` and does not copy the control. In order to work with the control, you should cast it to the type of control that you expect -

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("myDropDownList");
```

this example would allow you to work with a DropDownList control in the OnRowDataBound event of a GridView.

Comment: Already doing that, I'm setting other properties, as said above, some of these are DDL-specific.

Comment: ok, where is your DropDownList - is it inside a GridView, inside an UpdatePanel? would you be able to post some of your aspx markup and code-behind?

Comment: Nah, it's just straight on the page, I'm using findcontrol as there are multiple dropdowns with the names "CategoryIDropdown" where I is a number from one to a dynamic number based on information provided on page load. and I can't really post the aspx, not allowed by contract.

Comment: ok, where are you setting the visibility? it could be a case that the visibility is set in one event handler method and then is overridden if/when Page_Load is runs again after that method

Comment: it's set at the end of page_load, but the visibilty is reverted *instantly*, literally the line of code after.
There's a method that renders some of the controls invisible to start with, but it's run right at the start of the Page_Load.

Comment: do you have EnableViewState set on the control?